# "My other" or "My another"

Tags: word-choice, determiners

Which of these two sentences are correct?

> a) My other sister is taller than me
>   b) My another sister is taller than me

Answer (score 5):

Each noun phrase has **one** determiner slot.  It can't have two determiners in a row.

> [**My** other sister] is taller than me.

This sentence is fine.

In the noun phrase ***my other sister***, the determiner slot is filled by ***my***, a genitive pronoun.  The following word ***other*** is an adjective, not a determiner.

> [**Another** sister] is taller than me, too.

This sentence is also fine.

In the noun phrase ***another sister***, the determiner slot is filled by ***another***, a determinative.  This word was formed by compounding ***an + other***.

I'm sure you already know you can't put ***my*** and ***an*** together, because that would be two determiners together.  For the same reason, you can't put ***my*** and ***another*** together.

> *[**My another** sister] is taller than me.

This sentence is ungrammatical.

Why?  Because the noun phrase only has **one** determiner slot, but you've tried to fill it **twice**.

---

In this answer, the * symbol marks a sentence as ungrammatical.

(Reference: *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (2002), p.391)

Answer (score 2):

a) is correct. You could say "Another sister is taller..." but **not** "My another sister..."

Answer (score 0):

b) is incorrect. [***another***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/another) as used in b) is a pronoun (def. 4). You can't use two pronouns (my, another) together like this.

a) is OK. In this example, [***other***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/other) is an adjective (def. 1).